# overriding css.after and .before in c# server side

Tags: c#, html, css

i have a code like this :

```
string UserPic="images/1.png";
    DataTable Chat_dt = new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).getQueryResult(query);
    if (Chat_dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in Chat_dt.Rows)
        {
            if (row["MESSAGE_SENDER_ID"].ToString() == UserID)
            {
                ToAppend += "<div class='bubbledLeft' >"
                         + row["MESSAGE_BODY"].ToString()
                         + "</div>";
            }
            else
            {
                ToAppend += "<div class='bubbledRight' >"
                         + row["MESSAGE_BODY"].ToString()
                         + "</div>";
            }
        }

    }
```

css

```
.bubbledLeft:after{
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
left: -36px;
width: 32px;
bottom: 0px;
height: 32px;
content:"";

/*background-image: url(left_chatter.png);*/
background-size: 32px 32px;
background-position: bottom left;

border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
-moz-border-radius: 3px;    
-o-border-radius: 3px;  
-ms-border-radius: 3px; 
}
```

my question is how can i modify the `.bubbledLeft:after` `background-image` and set it as `UserPic` from the server side function? is that possible ?

**PS:**the server side function is an ajax request where on success i append the resulting html in a div

Comment: the only way to change the style of a pseudo-element is by modifying the CSS file. You can do this via Javascript as well as modify the file directly.

Comment: could you show me how ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do something as suggested in my comment, however looks like you can just append a `<style></style>` to the response with some style for the `.bubbledLeft:after` to override the current style (even with `!important` flag if needed):

```
//if the style does not override, you can try using the !important flag
ToAppend += "<style>.bubbledLeft:after { background-image: url(...); }</style>";
```